# Why group middleware does not work for apiResources?

Tags: laravel

Here is a API routing with sanctum:

```
   Route::group(["middleware" => "auth:sanctum"], function () {
        Route::apiResources([
            'profile' => ProfileController::class,
            'specialization' => SpecializationController::class,
            'specialization/filter' => SpecializationController::class,
            'location' => LocationController::class,
        ]);
    });
```

When I ask any controller it returns a response despite the user is not authorized.

Why `Route::group(["middleware" => "auth:sanctum"], function () {}` does not work?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the value for the `middleware` key should be an `array`:

```
Route::group(["middleware" => ["auth:sanctum"]], function () {
    Route::apiResources([
        'profile' => ProfileController::class,
        'specialization' => SpecializationController::class,
        'specialization/filter' => SpecializationController::class,
        'location' => LocationController::class,
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Still does not, I call api route without auth it returns data

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/location

Comment: @Faruh How are you calling the `API`, do you get any messages back?